# Trying to delete video recorded from phone

Tags: android, video

I use the following code to delete the recently recorded video, using ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURED) {


            Uri uri = data.getData();
            String path;
            String[] proj = {MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, proj, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            path = cursor.getString(column_index);



            File file = new File(path);
            if(file.exists())
            { 
                boolean del = file.delete();
                Log.v(TAG, del+"");
            }
```

The path from the cursor is correct, file exsist, but the file doesn't get deleted as it should. What am I missing?

I even have the android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: Your question should only contain the 'question' part. If you have an answer, please post it as an answer; or accept an answer that answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure the permission is set in the correct location of your Manifest
- Maybe the file is in use, add check for exceptions so you can get more details

Besides that the code looks fine.

Comment: java.io.File.delete() doesn't cast any Exceptions, but only returns true or false. In my case it returns false, and nothing else.

Comment: The problem was in my permission. I had to use <uses-permission> instead of <persmission>